# NoClassDefFoundError: kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.ReflectionFactoryImpl

Tags: java, android, kotlin, proguard, kotlin-android-extensions

I am using Kotlin in my project and have enabled Proguard.

I am getting an error in following method from `java.lang` class:

```
@Override
protected Class<?> findClass(String name) throws ClassNotFoundException {
    return Class.classForName(name, false, null);
}
```

Error:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader
>   kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.ReflectionFactoryImpl

Tried this but still problem persists:

```
-keep class kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.** {
*;
}
-dontwarn kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.**
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you taking into account the package for String name?

Class.forName(); takes into account the package as well, so if your class is located in the package mypackage.util.ClassHere then you would have the String input as "mypackage.util.MyClass".

I have never used Kotlin before so it may be an issue that persists with that language if the above suggestion does not work.

Comment: Class name is `kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.ReflectionFactoryImpl`

Comment: I am inputting fully qualified class name.